# Hermitian operator satisfies: $\text{Ran}(A^2) = \text{Ran}(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I came across a proof with a reference to the fact that, $\text{Ran}(A^2) = \text{Ran}(A)$, when $A$ is a Hermitian operator, but there is no formal lemma to this. I assume because it is simple, but I don't see how so yet. So, formally

> Suppose $A: V \mapsto V$ is a Hermitian operator, i.e. $\langle Av, w\rangle = \langle v, Aw \rangle, \forall v,w \in V$. Then $\text{Ran}(A^2) = \text{Ran}(A)$.

**What I've done:** I assume it goes something like the following. Let $w \in \text{Ran}(A^2)$.

$$\langle A^2v, w\rangle = \langle Av, Aw \rangle = \cdots = \langle Av, w\rangle ,$$

and we conclude $w \in \text{Ran}(A)$. But I don't quite see how we get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $y\in {\rm Im}(A)^\perp$.  Then $\langle y, A^2y\rangle=0$, so $\langle Ay, Ay\rangle=0$ and $Ay=0$ so $y\in {\rm ker}(A)$.

Thus ${\rm Im}(A)^\perp\subseteq {\rm ker}(A)$.

As $V={\rm Im}(A)\oplus{\rm Im}(A)^\perp$, we have that for any $x\in V$, we may write $x=Az+k$ with $k\in  {\rm ker}(A) $ and $z\in V$.

Thus:  $$Ax=A(Az+k)=A^2z.$$

Comment: Just to be clear: for, $x = Ay + k$, the $y$ referenced here is in the $\text{Im}(A)$, not the orthogonal complement as specified above it, correct?

Comment: It can be any vector in $V$ - I have changed $y$ to $z$ to avoid confusion.  So $Az$ will be in Im$(A)$.